# Select a part of R object that it is between quotes

Tags: r, regex

I have an odd character R object that derived from a pictures database. I need to select the first element (in this case 53244000). This has to be done to hundreds files, therefore I need something generic to say "take the first information that is between quotation marks `"`.

Any tip?

```
" 53244000\", \"tr 3450000\\034\\002\\031\", \"more keywords\", \"\", \"\\001\\023\\001\\031\\001\\037\\001%\\001+\\0012\\0018\\001>\\001E\\001L\\001R\\001Y\\001`\\001g\\001n\\001u\\001|\\001\\x83\\001\\x8b\\001\\x92\\001\\x9a\\001\\xa1\\001\\xa9\\001\\xb1\\001\\xb9\\001\\xc1\\001\\xc9\\001\\xd1\\001\\xd9\\001\\xe1\\001\\xe9\\001\\xf2\\001\\xfa\\002\\003\\002\\f\\002\\024\\002\\035\\002&\\002/\\0028\\002A\\002K\\002T\\002]\\002g\\002q\\002z\\002\\x84\\002\\x8e\\002\\x98\\002\\xa2\\002\\xac\\002\\xb6\\002\\xc1\\002\\xcb\\002\\xd5\\002\\xe0\\002\\xeb\\00
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide an example of your input data.

Comment: probably something like `sub('[^"]*"([^"]+)\".+', "\\1", your_string)`

Comment: what is the class of that object?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works!

Comment: @Cath, if you post your comment as an answer we could close this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to capture what is in between the first quotes with `sub` :

```
sub('[^"]*\"([^"]+)\".+', "\\1", your_string)
```

*Explanation:*

- `[^"]*` : anything but a quote 0 or more time
- `\"` : a quote
- `(([^"]+)` : anything but a quote one or more times, in between parentheses because this is what you want to capture (with `\\1`)
- `\"` : a quote
- `.+` : anything one or more times

Comment: So, if I get this straight (I often find regular expressions hard to read), your regular expression does the following: 
1. Anything not a quotation mark preceding what is in between quotation marks; 0 or more time because of the *
2. A quotation mark, that marks the start of the quote you look for.
3. Anything that is not a quotation mark, al least 1 time, because of the +; in between parenthesis to enable back-referencing with \\N
4. Close quote with a second quotation mark
5. Anything after that quote due to the .  , assuming there is always something after the quote because of the +

Comment: @4rj4n exactly :-)